# How to access Database by connection name from azure cloud service in webrole?

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-cloud-services

In Azure website, you can link database to the website and then configure it so that you can access the db through connection name, instead of connection string. This way you don't need to include the credentials in the connection string. But I couldn't figure out the same for cloud service (in webrole if it matters). Is it possible to do this from cloud service at all? Any reason if not? If not, what's the point to make the database as linked resources?

Answer (score 0):

If you link a database to your cloud service, if you try to delete one of the other, you'll be warned that it is linked.  This prevent you from deleting by mistake a service that is currently used.